# convert SAFELY 64 bit app into a 32/64bit app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, x86, 64-bit, automatic-ref-counting

i made an app (my first one) with ARC enabled, distributed (not over the appstore) and started getting reports that it crashed on some macs. after trying and searaching with theyr help we found out that the problem is that they have a 32 bit processor. so i disabled ARC, set the build to x86_64 and got a load of error messages.

all of them have been sorted, and now i am left with a load of warnings (yellow ones). i am worried that i forget something and make a mess with the memory. what is in your opinion the best way to get froma 64 bit app to a 32/64 bit app without forgetting something?
why is ARC used in the first place if there are many macs that aren't compatible with it?

thanks!

-----UPDATE ------

as reuquested:

```
 Update to recommended settings

 Property 'delegate' requires method 'delegate' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

 Property 'delegate' requires method 'setDelegate:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

 '__bridge' casts have no effect when not using ARC

 Variable 'loc_tip' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is false

 Variable 'loc_tip' is used uninitialized whenever '&&' condition is false

 Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'tableView:toolTipForCell:rect:tableColumn:row:mouseLocation:': 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') vs 'long'
```

Comment: We would love to see the actual warnings to decide what potential mistakes they correspond to.

Comment: “many” is rather debatable in the absence of a number; it's certainly not “most”, since there have been 64-bit-compatible Macs since 2006, which is the same year Macs went Intel. The first Intel Macs had 32-bit-only processors, but every one of those models was replaced with a 64-bit-compatible successor within about a year. As an extremely rough guess, one could say that 6/7ths of the Intel Mac population is 64-bit-compatible. (For much better estimates, see Adium's and the Omni Group's software-update statistics.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rough Water Ahead**

> all of them have been sorted, and now i am left with a load of warnings (yellow ones).

turn up the warning level. fix them all.

> i am worried that i forget something and make a mess with the memory.
>
> what is in your opinion the best way to get froma 64 bit app to a 32/64 bit app without forgetting something?

worry is natural, considering the problem.

one quick fix would be to use ObjC with Garbage Collection enabled. doing so and trusting it will just work with no extra changes is a mistake (read: you should reserve a lot of time for testing and bug hunting).

the other approach, if you really want good support on both 32 and 64, would be to use MRC -- but you should just commit to MRC for both 32 and 64 bit in that case (no ARC). of course, this will require a **lot** of reviewing, fixing, manual testing, and testing for leaks (unless your program is small). this is the preferable solution for an app with good long term support and high quality standards, IMO.

> why is ARC used in the first place if there are many macs that aren't compatible with it?

there really *aren't* a whole lot of macs out there that require 32 bit. if you were releasing a 1.0 today, you should just consider making it 64 bit only.

32 bit should have been supported and tested from the beginning of development, if it was a requirement -- either the ARC option or 32 bit would have been eliminated very early on. it seems odd that this oversight would slip through testing and development.

> Update to recommended settings

Hit "Validate Settings", review, perform changes.

> Property 'delegate' requires method 'delegate' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

echo warning message

> Property 'delegate' requires method 'setDelegate:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

echo warning message

> '__bridge' casts have no effect when not using ARC

you would just use a c-style cast in that case

> Variable 'loc_tip' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is false

ARC does this for you. just do what ARC would do:

```
NSSomething * loc_tip = nil;
```

> Variable 'loc_tip' is used uninitialized whenever '&&' condition is false

echo previous response

> Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'tableView:toolTipForCell:rect:tableColumn:row:mouseLocation:': 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') vs 'long'

the selector's declaration does not match -- copy the declaration from the header (`NSTableView.h`) and see if that change (of parameter types) requires any other changes to your implementations.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! unfortunately it smy first app so i didnt know that it wont be compatible with some macs. i'l probably stick to the 64 bit version, and have a 32 bit version that will not be further developed.

Comment: @Justme yeah - cutting the 32 bit variant is the quick solution. hopefully it doesn't affect many customers.

Comment: @PeterHosey cool +1. for clang, i just start with `-Weverything` enabled, then disable the ones i won't fix (e.g. padding). maybe i should create my own repo with my warning set…

Comment: thanks guys! just a quick question.. after further researches i found out that it is not the 64 bit the problem. the problem is the IOS version. 10.6.8 does not work. all above does. i have removed all bugs even in 64 bit version with peter's script. what seems odd to me is that if i build for a 32 bit version then it works also on 10.6.8. why could that be?

Comment: @Justme it could be a **lot** of reasons. many components/implementations change in major release versions. you need to identify the problem. determining that an app crashes when run on one OS version, but not another -- could be a million things. that is not a specific problem, and cannot be given a specific answer.

Comment: thanks Justin. Could the fact that compiling with 32 bit compatibiliy makes it work help me move in the right direction? how could i search for the problem if i dont have a crashing system in the first place? wouldnt it have to tell while compiling if the file is not compatible?

Comment: @Justme IOW, you are saying that since fixing problems which the compiler noted with warnings, the crash is no longer reproducible? i can't answer that because i don't know which changes you have made in the process of removing the issues noted by the warnings. if you want to know, you will have to go through your commits. i'm in no position to advise, sorry.

Comment: the situation is this: an app written with ARC on in 64 bit mode works on all systems above 10.6.8. same app crashes on 10.6.8. i disable arc, firx the RED errors (urgent ones just so that it compiles) and it runs without problems on 10.6.8. but i will try to set up a virtual machine with 10.6.8. thanks anyway! best reagrds and have a nice weekend!

Comment: @Justme: Check your Deployment Target setting, and make sure you aren't trying to do `weak` properties or `__weak` instance variables. ARC with weak references requires Lion, but ARC without weak references is supposed to work on 10.6. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/